# Automatic Set Japanese on Textfield focus

Tags: validation, unicode, internationalization, character, textfield

I have a web application. It is running on struts framework but i dnt think it's relevant to my question. :)

I want that when I click or put my cursor on my textbox I can directly type japanese katakana, hiragana and kanji characters.

Windows has this IME which enables you to type these characters by enabling japanese or any language by pressing alt + ~ or depending on your setting. What IO want is I dnt have to do this. IT should be automatic.

Is this possible with javascript or any technology? PLease help

Comment: I've changed **nihongo** to **japanese**, because the term "nihongo" is too localized :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ime-mode: active
```

in css style, basically you could set auto, turn on, turn off by default for IME

More info regarding `ime-mode` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530767%28VS.85%29.aspx) & [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/ime-mode)

Comment: tnx. i'll check this out. It would be great too if we can enforce only nihongo typing.

Comment: I don't think an html element could force the host computer IME though, I think its just an indicator to client computer's IME to turn on / off, IMHO.

Comment: This will do anyway... Tnx. But I am trying　find a way to deactivate ime back when i leave this textfield so that I can type romaji directly all other fields without having to deactivate it manually. BUt im posting this prob on a different thread though.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external javascript library, such as [wanakana.js](https://wanakana.com/).

Here's an example:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wanakana"></script>

<input type="text" id="wanakana-input"/>
<script>
  var textInput = document.getElementById('wanakana-input');
  wanakana.bind(textInput, /* options */); // uses IMEMode with toKana() as default
  // to remove event listeners: wanakana.unbind(textInput);
  </script>
```